# How to put character time data into a factor

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

dataframe(Mydata) contains values.

```
Delivery.Time   Customer.Name              Product.Name
11:22:00        Grace Wangen               Insalatone pollo
19:46:47        ystein Skagestad           CLASSIC CHEESEBURGER
08:54:20        Hans Hallseth              Latte
15:25:21        Thomas Stlen               SUSHI MORIAWASE     
14:45:00        Ingvild Berg               SUSHI CHIISAI
12:45:33        Christopher Frenning       Funghi

Mydata["Delivery.Labels"] <- NA   ## Added new columns

deliBreaks <- c("19:00:00","05:00:00","11:00:00","12:00:00","15:00:00")


Mydata$Delivery.Labels <-c("Dinner", "Breakfast", "Brunch", "Lunch", "Snackstime")[ findInterval(chron(times=Mydata$Delivery.Time), chron(times=deliBreaks))]
```

While running code, I am getting below error message.

> 'vec' must be sorted non-decreasingly

I looking for my table look like this.

```
Delivery.Time   Customer.Name              Product.Name                      Delivery.Lables 

11:22:00        Grace Wangen               Insalatone pollo           Brunch
19:46:47        ystein Skagestad           CLASSIC CHEESEBURGER           Dinner
08:54:20        Hans Hallseth              Latte                      Breakfast
15:25:21        Thomas Stlen               SUSHI MORIAWASE                Snackstime
14:45:00        Ingvild Berg               SUSHI CHIISAI              Lunch
12:45:33        Christopher Frenning       Funghi                     Lunch
```

Comment: Can you please write out the question and explain in some sentences what you want?

Comment: Error message ('vec' must be sorted non-decreasingly) @Elin

Comment: Make sure you are entering the `deliBreaks` as times not strings.

Comment: Changed but no right result. @Elin

Comment: Please help me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do it with a minimal example. 
First convert your data to time data.
Then use the cut() function to divide up the data into time blocks.

```
time<- strptime(c("11:22:00", "19:46:47", "08:54:20", "15:25:21", "14:45:00", "12:45:33"),  format= "%T") 


Delivery.Labels <-    cut(time, breaks = strptime(c("00:00:01", "11:00:00","12:00:00","15:00:00", "19:00:00", "23:59:59"),  "%T"), 
        labels = c("Breakfast", "Brunch", "Lunch", "Snackstime", "Dinner"), 
       right = TRUE,
        include.lowest=TRUE
        )
```

strptime() converts the strings to time. 
cut() puts your data into bins.
You might want to make the resulting factor ordered.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.